# Datos de un archivo en diferentes variables

Tags: c++

Tengo el siguiente `archivo.txt` que contiene :

```
32 10 11
==========
=#=@===x==
=x#.....#=
=.=#==.#.=
=..x====.=
===.#===.=
=...==.#x=
=.==x===.=
=..#....x=
==#=x.====
==========
```

Realice un codigo que me almacena lo que contiene el `archivo.txt` en una variable, es el siguiente:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <fstream>
using namespace std;

void mapa();

int main() {
    mapa();

    system("pause");
    return 0;
}

void mapa(){
    ifstream archivo;
    string texto;


    archivo.open("Entrada.txt", ios::in); //abrimos el archivo

    if(archivo.fail()){
        cout<<"Ocurrio un error con el archivo.";
        exit(1);
    }

    while(!archivo.eof()){ //mientras no sea el final del archivo
        getline(archivo, texto);
        cout<<texto<<endl;

    }

    archivo.close(); //cerramos el archivo

}
```

Mi duda es la siguiente, como podria almacenar la primera fila en variables distintas (32, 10, 11) y luego el resto en una matriz? Se supone que es un mapa.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Los números es muy facil leerlos... independientemente de que tengan 1, 2 o mil espacios entre medias su lectura es tan simple o complicada como:

```
int valor1, valor2, valor 3;
archivo >> valor1 >> valor2 >> valor3;
```

Ya que el operador de extracción descarta los espacios en blanco.

Lo siguiente es leer el mapa... aquí tendrías que decidir si lo quieres leer linealizado o separado por filas. Sin embargo esto afecta únicamente a la variable donde lo almacenas, no a la forma de leer los datos.

Para leer cada línea en una fila:

```
std::vector<std::string>> mapa;

while(!archivo.eof()){
    std::string linea;
    archivo >> linea;
    mapa.push_back(linea);
}
```

Mientras que para linealizar el mapa...

```
std::string mapa;

while(!archivo.eof()){
    std::string linea;
    archivo >> linea;
    mapa += linea;
}
```

Nota que no hace falta usar `getline` ... esto es así porque no hay espacios en el mapa. Si los hubiese deberías usar `getline` para que no se descartasen.
Si lo ponemos todo junto nos quedaría algo así:

```
int valor1, valor2, valor 3;
std::vector<std::string>> mapa;

archivo.open("Entrada.txt", ios::in); //abrimos el archivo

if(archivo.fail()){
    cout<<"Ocurrio un error con el archivo.";
    exit(1);
}

archivo >> valor1 >> valor2 >> valor3;

while(!archivo.eof()){ //mientras no sea el final del archivo
    std::string linea;
    archivo >> linea;
    mapa.push_back(linea);
}
```

Comment: Muchas gracias, la forma en que lo realizaste es mucho mas entendible y exacta de lo que habia pensado